# Running external exe in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to run an external executable written in fortran which provides one of the inputs inside a python code.

Is it possible to run that exe inside Python script?

Comment: I suggest migrating this question to SO if it doesn't get a quick answer here, because it really is seeking pure Python expertise.  (You can migrate it by following the "flag" link to contact a moderator.)

Comment: I think subprocess is the way to do this nowadays.

Comment: In addition, googling for "python run extrnal executable" got me the answer quite quickly. No offense, but have you tried this?

Comment: I wasn't aware subprocess before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/subprocess.html) module.

E.g:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
exit_code=proc.wait()
print exit_code,stdout.read(),stderr.read()
```

Answer (score 4):

Look into [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) and related Python stuff. SO is a good place to ask related questions.

Comment: Sorry for missing one important point that i have to run it in the arcgis environment.

Comment: I'm not sure how that matters. If you're using a Python script, you should have access to any of the Python libraries.